# Redirect after plugin activation

Tags: wordpress

How do I redirect users to my plugin settings page after they activate my plugin, I tried

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'activate_myplugin');
function activate_myplugin()
{
//create and populate DB tables
wp_redirect(plugin_setting_url);
}
```

but it does not work.

Comment: I searched on google, didn't get anything... same question is on some other forums, all are unanswered

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate');
add_action('admin_init', 'my_plugin_redirect');

function my_plugin_activate() {
    add_option('my_plugin_do_activation_redirect', true);
}

function my_plugin_redirect() {
    if (get_option('my_plugin_do_activation_redirect', false)) {
        delete_option('my_plugin_do_activation_redirect');
        wp_redirect(MY_PLUGIN_SETTINGS_URL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This will redirect to option page only if that plugin is activated only without using bulk activation mode .

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate');
add_action('admin_init', 'my_plugin_redirect');

function my_plugin_activate() {
    add_option('my_plugin_do_activation_redirect', true);
}

function my_plugin_redirect() {
    if (get_option('my_plugin_do_activation_redirect', false)) {
        delete_option('my_plugin_do_activation_redirect');
        if(!isset($_GET['activate-multi']))
        {
            wp_redirect("options-general.php?page=your-plugin-option-page");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

thanks for your code - it´s great, but only has one downside: upon bulk activation of plugins, you also get redirected to your defined redirect page - which might confuse user when deactivating/activating all plugins at once for test/debug reason. I therefore would propose the solution, to add an option to only redirect to your page on FIRST plugin activation:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate');
add_action('admin_init', 'my_plugin_redirect');

function my_plugin_activate() {
add_option('myplugin_redirect_on_first_activation', 'true');
}

function my_plugin_redirect() {
    if (get_option(MYPLUGIN_REDIRECT_ON_FIRST_ACTIVATION_KEY) == 'true') {
        update_option(MYPLUGIN_REDIRECT_ON_FIRST_ACTIVATION_KEY, 'false');
        wp_redirect(MY_PLUGIN_SETTINGS_URL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry it's very simple.
Simply paste this code in you  plugin.php file

```php
function_activation_redirect( ) {
    exit( wp_redirect( 'http://45.118.207.78/amarwp/wp-admin/admin.php?page=custompage'  ) )
}
add_action( 'activated_plugin', 'funtion_activation_redirect' );
```

http://45.118.207.78/amarwp/wp-admin/admin.php?page=custompage
in my case this is the path of my page where I want to redirect my page.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have used bellows code redirect after plugin activation. You can use this code. It's working nicely.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'nht_plugin_activate');
add_action('admin_init', 'nht_plugin_redirect');

function nht_plugin_activate() {
add_option('nht_plugin_do_activation_redirect', true);
}

function nht_plugin_redirect() {
if (get_option('nht_plugin_do_activation_redirect', false)) {
    delete_option('nht_plugin_do_activation_redirect');
    if(!isset($_GET['activate-multi']))
    {
        wp_redirect("edit.php?post_type=headline&page=news-headline");
    }
 }
}
```

nht_ is my plugin prefix & "edit.php?post_type=headline&page=news-headline" is redirect page. please replace this those.